# windows - Changing HTTP response

Tags: windows, http

i have a windows 10 computer and a program, that sends to a server (xxx.com aka x.x.x.x) a request. server responses with, for example, "false". that program reads that response and based on that gives output. I need to locally (not on the server, only for me) change that value for, for example, "true". I tried Charles, but it doesn't work for my soft (in browser same requests that go through Charles give "true"). What is the problem here?

Comment: What is Charles?

Comment: @Antimony Charles is an HTTP proxy software and OP tried to intercept the HTTP request&response through it.

Comment: By using Charles, do you mean it works well in browser (return `true`), but it does not work in your program?

Comment: @shaochuancs, exactly

Answer (score 0):

Charles "doesn't work" for your program because the HTTP request sent from your program is not intercepted. Charles can autoconfigure the proxy setting for browsers, that's why in your browser "same requests that go through Charles give `true`".

In order to make Charles intercept your program's HTTP request, a reverse proxy need to be configured:

Step 1. Launch Charles, and go to *Proxy* - *Reverse Proxies...*

Step 2. Check *Enable Reverse Proxies* and click *Add*.

Step 3. Configure a reverse proxy:

```
Local port: 59110 // any unused local port
Remote host: xxx.com // the target server
Remote port: 80 // the port opened in target server
```

Step 4. In your program, send all HTTP requests to `localhost:59110`.

In this way, Charles can intercept all HTTP requests sent from your program, and you can change the HTTP response data.

If the target server provides HTTPS service instead of HTTP, some additional work need to be done:

SSL-Step 1. In Charles, go to *Proxy* - *SSL Proxying Settings* - *SSL Proxying*

SSL-Step 2. Check *Enable SSL Proxying* and click *Add*:

SSL-Step 3. Configure an SSL proxy:

```
Host: xxx.com // the target server
Port: 443 // the SSL port opened in target server
```

SSL-Step 4 (1). go to *Help* - *SSL Proxying* - *Install Charles Root Certificate*. This will allow your program trust the self-generated certificate from Charles.

or

SSL-Step (2). If you don't want to install Charles' root CA, you can change your program to prevent certificate error. For example, in Node.js, the following code can prevent program from rejecting unauthorized certificate:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

Comment: i'm sorry if it is a dumb question, but how to send all HTTP requests to local proxy if my program doesn't include proxy setting?

Comment: @МаксСоколов without config for your program, it's impossible to make it send HTTP requests to local proxy. Please check: https://superuser.com/questions/398977/how-can-i-run-all-http-request-through-charles-web-debugging-proxy-including-c  note Kevin's explanation: The reason why you don't just get proxying of all HTTP requests is because at the operating system level, there is no such thing as a "HTTP request"; there are only TCP connections.